# How are you supposed to know what crimp tool to use for a given connector?

Tags: connector, wire-terminals, crimp

There is a dizzying array of crimping tools available on digi-key, mouser, and other distributors. But they nearly always just say they're for specific wire gauges, without reference to what type of connector they're meant for--and just today I came up against a problem where a crimping die I'd paid $50 for turned out to not work at all for the terminal I was trying to crimp onto the wire; even using the 6 AWG hole didn't fit (it's 8 AWG wire with an ordinary uninsulated brazed-seam lug). How are you supposed to know which tool to use for which type of crimp?

I'm aware that manufacturers usually list a specific tool to use, but I can't afford to pay $3000 and wait out a ten-week lead time just to get a few terminals crimped onto some wire.

It'd be greatly appreciated--and hopefully of use to others as well--if someone could give a run-down of different types of common crimp connectors and what sort of tool they're intended to be used with.

Comment: With TLAR......

Comment: @DKNguyen Sorry, what's TLAR?

Comment: "That looks about right."

Comment: @DKNguyen I'd prefer to not spend $50 on a crimp die just to find out it doesn't work, though!

Comment: And every crimp tool I see does say what type it is meant for. I compare the shape against the official crimper.

Comment: @DKNguyen The one I used said it was for "6, 8, and 10 AWG wire terminals", but apparently that doesn't include the sort of thick lugs I was using.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah don't buy those unless you recognize the shapes used. I learned most of my shapes from looking at Paladin/GreenLee CrimpAll dies. Also helpful are PowerWerx TriCrimp dies.

Comment: A guide to the shapes is exactly what I'm looking for in an answer to this question; if you can provide one, that would be great.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/crimpall-1300-8000-series/22980
https://powerwerx.com/tricrimp-tridies-accessory-die-sets http://www.lashenelectronics.com/p-1370-paladin-die-sets-for-crimpall8000-1300-series.aspx

Comment: Paladin Tools was much more informative before GreenLee bought them and stripped away all the info.

Comment: https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1MbD9MVXXXXaFXVXXq6xXFXXXf/1pcs-Special-Crimping-Dies-Jaw-Crimp-Die-Replaceable-crimping-die-sets-for-Ferrules-Crimper-Crimping-Tool.jpg

Comment: I'm starting to think I just need to get one of these crimpall tools and I'll be set!

Comment: I avoid single die crimpers in general. Note that the dies aren't necessarily interchangeable between handles of different brands. At >10AWG you tend to need different crimpers for welding cable. The ones I linked max out around 10AWG if not 12AWG.

Comment: Yeah, the one I have has interchangeable dies, but it's an Aven Tools brand one and doesn't seem compatible with any of the other brands' crimp dies that I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

This is not for professional use cases, but I use pliers in the DIY situation. Either tiny little ones, or the really big 10" ones. I form the metal onto the wire just sufficiently enough to retain it. I then flux and solder it on with an appropriately sized iron.

Whilst perhaps not approved for aeronautical/military use, and slow, the advantage is that I can 'crimp' a large range of terminals with common general purpose tools.

Comment: I've done this before as well, though some of the connectors I've been working with need quite a lot of force to crimp; battery lugs made of approximately 2mm thick copper are *not* easily crimped with hand pliers! Pliers are pretty good, with careful use, for open-barrel contacts, though.

Comment: @Hearth Absolutely. You can also use [water pump pliers](https://cdn.aws.toolstation.com/images/141020-UK/800/49029.jpg) or a vice. And you can go to a blow torch for the big stuff. Just use a little delicacy.